# fork() child exec command outputting weirdly

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec

I am trying to do ls -la | wc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pipes=3;
    char *ls[] = {"ls","-la",NULL};
    char *wc[] = {"wc",NULL};
    char *base64[] = {"base64","-w0",NULL};
    //char **commands[] = {ls,wc,base64};

    int fds[pipes][2];
    for(int i=0;i<pipes;i++)
    {
        int err = pipe(fds[i]);
        if(err == -1)
        {
            perror("Pipe failed.\n");
        }
    }
    int status;
    pid_t childPid;
    //Child 1.
    if((childPid = fork()) == 0)    
    {
        dup2(fds[0][1],1);
        for(int i=0;i<pipes;i++)
        {
            close(fds[i][0]); 
            close(fds[i][1]);
        }
        execvp(ls[0],ls);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(childPid == -1)
    {
        perror("Child 1 failed.\n");
    }
    // Second child.
    if((childPid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(fds[0][0],0);
        for(int i=0;i<pipes;i++)
        {
            close(fds[i][0]); 
            close(fds[i][1]);
        }
        execvp(wc[0],wc);
    }
    else if(childPid == -1)
    {
        perror("Child 2 failed.\n");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<pipes;i++)
    {
        close(fds[i][0]);
        close(fds[i][1]);
    }
    waitpid(childPid,&status,WUNTRACED|WNOHANG);
    return 0;
}
```

out expect:

> root@danial#gcc -o pip pip.c
>
> root@danial#./pip
>
> ```
> 10      83     436
> ```

output I am getting:

> root@danial#./pip
>
> root@danial#     10      83     436
>
> cursor stays here until I press enter key.

I tried doing this without pipes just wrote a simple program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        execlp("ls","ls","-la",NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and samething happend:

> root@danial#./test
>
> root@danial#total 84
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 30 06:49 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 9 root root  4096 Mar 29 09:33 ..
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16960 Mar 30 06:49 pip
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1310 Mar 30 06:48 pip.c

Comment: Child is waiting to output and parent is waiting on child, isn't it?

Comment: When your program starts, it forks the child and then terminates.   The shell therefore issues a prompt.   All that is happening is that the shell issues the prompt before the child produces output.    Since the order of execution of distinct processes is arbitrary (and can be interleaved), what you are seeing is not unexpected.    If you want the child to produce output before the parent terminates, then the parent needs to wait for the child to complete.

Comment: Ok I just tried waitipid(pid,&status,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED); that didnt work but when I tried wait(NULL); it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
waitpid(childPid,&status,WUNTRACED|WNOHANG);
```

With the `WNOHANG` you tell `waitpid` to poll the status, and then return *immediately* withoput actually waiting.

When the `waitpid` call returns, you exit the parent process, leaving your *two* child-processes orphaned.

And what happens when the parent process exiting is that its parent process (the shell) taking over and printing the prompt. *Then* your child-processes prints their output. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you press to "clear" the output is simply empty input for the shell.

You need to wait for *both* your child processes.

Comment: Yes I just checked waitpid(childPid,&status,0) or wait(NULL) fixes the problem.

Comment: @DanialAhmed Not that it will only wait for *one* child process. You're not reaping both.

Comment: then can you tell me what should I do to fix it? I should only use WUNTRACED?

Comment: @DanialAhmed Call `waitpid` or `wait` twice. Once for each child you create.

Comment: That is working either? http://prntscr.com/n51bqm now I am not getting any output even pressing enter doesnt work?

Comment: @DanialAhmed Think a little... The first `wait` will wait for the first child, but that first child won't be able to exit until the *second* child have read the data from the pipe. You need to wait for both children *after* both have been started.

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you. I created an array of childpids. int childPids[pipes] and now in loop I am waiting for each of the child. waitpid(childPids[i],&status,0). Is the the correct way to do it? Or am I missing something again?